# FCM google account

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the FCM and it was working fine. I have not released any final apk. So It was debug APK. after a time i thought to make it final/release apk. I knew I have to make some key changes to make fcm work on release version of apk.

But the problem is that I do not remember now which account I used to make the fcm file and other settings. I do not remember which email Id I used to create the project on the FCM. Still my app is working fine.

I just wanted to know its account. Can I have any clue from the google-json file that I have downloaded from the FCM account. ?? please help

Comment: nope you don't know about it.But if you want to made any changes like FCM paid account or anything would you like to change then please make new account and register your project again and put those json file into hierarchy.

Comment: @jyubinpatel so you are saying to make entirely new project on other email Id. and make the json file using that account. and move those json file into my project and replace file with older google-json file ?

Comment: yes but those thing done when you want to change anything into FCM account.

Comment: sorry I did not get you what you said in last comment.

Comment: Well, if you have the known list of your emails, you could try opening each of them and match the **project-id** of the app. If found, bingo!!

Comment: Or you could try opening **firebase_url**, which will ask you to login with the same email used to create the project in console. If it succeeds you'll have your console opened, otherwise, error saying *The project 'myproject-24dj2' either does not exist, or ''thisemail@gmail.com' doesn't have permission to view it.*

Comment: I mean when you want to Add new feature implementation like firebase analytics is a new which you need to implement in your app at that time you lost your id on which you register your app so that time need to create new app in other email-id and and setup all which you are using into app and last you need to replace your json file with new one.Hope you understand.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes matching project id is good idea. but I do not have list of ids.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes what firebase_url are you talking about ?. And how it will give error like you mentioned "'myproject-24dj2'"

Comment: @Androidteem **firebase_url** can be found from the google json file. Open it in a browser, you'll be asked to login and on success, it will redirect you to your **project** for this url in the console.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes I tried opening the google.json file in browser and it got openened as expected. just like a text file

Comment: @Androidteem No! You just have to copy **firebase-url** from the json file. It's in the first json-object (keyed as *project_info*) in the file. Look it up.

Comment: wait let me test it. .

Comment: thats great hint too. thanks for helping me out guys